# Rendering view from form in Django

Tags: python, django, forms, user-input

I'm having issue getting the content from a form and displaying it on another page.

When I click submit, it directs me to the correct page but it does not load as there are errors in my function. I am also unsure how to display the content on the page.

My form:

```
<div class = "container">
<form action="{% url 'cleaner:result' %}" method ="post" >
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div>
    <label for="cv">Enter details: </label>
    <textarea name="cv" id='cv' rows="10" cols="30" maxlength="20000"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div>
  <button>Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'clean/result/$', views.ResultView.as_view(), name='result'),
```

My issue lies here, in **views.py**

```
class ResultView(View):

    template_name = 'cleaner/result.html'
    #Get details from form
    details = request.form.get("cv")
    def result(request):
        if details != '':

        return render(request, template_name)
```

This is not the correct way to get the content from the form. How can I get this?

```
details = request.form.get("cv")

NameError: name 'request' is not defined
```

After that, how do I display the content of the form?

I am using django 1.9 and python 3.6.4.

**edit:**

Here is working code if anyone comes across this:

```
class ResultView(View):

    template_name = 'cleaner/result.html'

    def post(self, request):
        #Get details from form
        details = request.POST.get("cv")

        if details != '':

            return render(request, self.template_name)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things wrong. Firstly, anything involving the request has to be done in a method, not at class level; classes are defined at import time, and there is no request at that point.

Secondly, there is no point defining a method called `request`. In a class based view, the main methods are named after the HTTP methods - `get` and `post` - so you need to override the relevant one here, ie `post`.

Thirdly, there is no `request.form` in Django; you're thinking of Flask. In Django you would need to use `request.POST`.

And finally, to display the content of the form you need to pass it as the context to the render function.